# Debugging code:: How to colors lines in CGContext?

Tags: swift, nsstring, cgcontext, quartz-core

The following code has an problem, for some reason the radial lines are being drawn black when they should be drawn in `UIColor.yellowColor()`

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore


let π:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI)

class CircularPlotView:UIView {

  var lineWidth:CGFloat = 1.5 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
  var edgeColor:UIColor = UIColor.yellowColor() { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
  var fillColor:UIColor = UIColor.orangeColor() { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
  var fieldColor:UIColor = UIColor.yellowColor(){ didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
  var lineColor:UIColor = UIColor.blueColor(){ didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
  var scale: CGFloat = 0.90 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
  //var plotCenter:CGPoint { return convertPoint(center, fromView: superview) }
  var plotCenter:CGPoint {return CGPoint(x: 190,y: 316) }
  var plotRadius:CGFloat {return min(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 8 * scale }
  var diameterX:CGFloat = 100.0
  var radiusX:CGFloat {return diameterX * 0.5}
  var scaleFactorDB:CGFloat = 5.0
  var offsetDB:CGFloat = 0.0

  //data to plot
  var dataString:[String] = ["cat","dog","pizza"]
  var dataDB:[Float] = [11.0,9.0,3.5]

  var fontSize:CGFloat = 17.0

  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    let fieldFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize)

    let paragraphStyle:NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.alloc()
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

    let attributes:Dictionary = [
      NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
      NSForegroundColorAttributeName: fieldColor,
      NSFontAttributeName: fieldFont
    ]


    var theta:CGFloat = 1.5 * π //CGFloat(M_PI)
    var radius:CGFloat = 0.0
    //var s:NSString = "ERROR FIX DATABASE" //if shown error in DB

    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

    //MARK:== draw strings ==
    //with enough separation so they don't clobber each other
    var myAttributedString:NSMutableAttributedString!

    for (var i=0; i < dataDB.count; i++)
    {
      //s = NSString(string: dataString[i])
      myAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString (string: dataString[i], attributes:attributes)

      theta =  1.97 * π * ( CGFloat(i) / (CGFloat(dataDB.count) ) )
      radius =  ( radiusX + 10.0 +  offsetDB + scaleFactorDB*CGFloat(dataDB.reduce(dataDB[0], { max($0, $1) })) )

      CGContextSaveGState(context)
      CGContextTranslateCTM(context,plotCenter.x ,plotCenter.y )
      CGContextRotateCTM(context, theta)
     CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor)
      CGContextMoveToPoint(context,0.0,0.0)
      CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, radiusX + scaleFactorDB*CGFloat(dataDB[i]) + offsetDB, 0.0 )
      myAttributedString.drawAtPoint(CGPoint(x: radius , y: 0 ))
      CGContextRestoreGState(context)
    }

    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    println("Time elapsed loop through lines and strings: \(timeElapsed) s")

    CGContextStrokePath(context)

    //MARK:== draw oval, fill, edge ==
    let sunPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(
      plotCenter.x - radiusX,
      plotCenter.y - radiusX,
      diameterX, diameterX)
    )

    sunPath.lineWidth = lineWidth

    edgeColor.set()
    sunPath.stroke()

    fillColor.setFill()
    sunPath.fill()

  }
```

Comment: What part of your code do you think "should" make those lines yellow? I see two places where `yellowColor()` is used: to initialize `fieldColor` and `edgeColor`. The former is only used for the attributed string foreground color and the latter is only used for the stroke of the "sun". You're not setting the (stroke) color before drawing the radial lines.

Comment: I added `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor)` just before `CGContextSaveGState(context)` and now it works.  Thanks.  Apparently you have to set the stroke before the state is saved.

Comment: You don't have to set the stroke color before the state is saved. You just have to do it before you stroke a line (or path). In fact, you should probably do it between the saving and restoring of the state so that it only affects what you intend it to.

Comment: If I do this `      CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,lineColor.CGColor)
      CGContextSaveGState(context)`    I get the correct color but if I do this `      CGContextSaveGState(context) CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,lineColor.CGColor)
      ` the lines are black??

Comment: You are moving the current point and then adding a line to another point. Those just build a path within the context. You need to call `CGContextStrokePath(context)` to stroke the current path. Frankly, I'm not sure how or why you're getting lines at all without that. I guess that drawing the attributed string effectively draws the current path first, but who knows what it does to the context beforehand. Stroke it yourself to make sure it does it right.

Comment: Thanks that works, I've modified the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was

```
  CGContextSaveGState(context)
  CGContextTranslateCTM(context,plotCenter.x ,plotCenter.y )
  CGContextRotateCTM(context, theta)
  CGContextMoveToPoint(context,0.0,0.0)
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, radiusX + scaleFactorDB*CGFloat(dataDB[i]) + offsetDB, 0.0 )
  myAttributedString.drawAtPoint(CGPoint(x: radius , y: 0 ))
  CGContextRestoreGState(context)
```

corrected

```
  CGContextSaveGState(context)
  CGContextTranslateCTM(context,plotCenter.x ,plotCenter.y )
  CGContextRotateCTM(context, theta)
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,lineColor.CGColor)
  CGContextMoveToPoint(context,0.0,0.0)
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, radiusX + scaleFactorDB*CGFloat(dataDB[i]) + offsetDB, 0.0 )
  CGContextStrokePath(context)
  myAttributedString.drawAtPoint(CGPoint(x: radius , y: 0 ))
  CGContextRestoreGState(context)
```